# How can I change the location of .xinitrc and .zsh* files

Tags: zsh, configuration, xinit

I want to change the location of `.xinitrc`, `.zshrc` and `.zshenv` to `~/.config/x/xinitrc`, `~/.config/zsh/zshrc` and `~/.config/zsh/zshenv`, but without simlinking them.

How can I achieve this? Do I have to change files that source these configuration files in `/etc`? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Both `xinit` and `zsh` can be told where to find their respective rc files with environment variables: `XINITRC` for `xinit` and `ZDOTDIR` for `zsh` (for the directory where to find `.zshrc`, `.zshenv`, `.zlogin`, `.zlogout`, `.zcompdump`...).

So you could try and seed the environment with those upon login.

For instance, if using a GNU/Linux distribution and the `pam_env` env modules, you could have:

```
XINITRC         DEFAULT=@{HOME}/.config/x/xinitrc
ZDOTDIR         DEFAULT=@{HOME}/.config/zsh
```

in `/etc/security/pam_env.conf`

Or:

```
XINITRC=/home/you/.config/x/xinitrc
ZDOTDIR=/home/you/.config/zsh
```

In your `~/.pam_environment` (see the `pam_env` man page for how to change the path of that one as well).

Answer (score 0):

i think you don't like my way , but i think is useful

```bsh
$ cat ~/.xinitrc

source ~/.config/x/xinitrc
```

```bsh
$ cat ~/.zshrc

source ~/.config/zsh/zshrc
```

this methode is keeping your configs in any directory without using symlink

Comment: Why would this method be preferred over a symlink?

Comment: if use git with a symlink or some backup something does not work